# custom font-face looks bad only in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I am using the `Noto Sans Hebrew` font-face from google's [early access](http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess) webfonts. And as usual, there's a rendering problem on windows.

On IE, things look... actually pretty good:

[image]

On Firefox & Chrome, things look kinda choppy (notice the fourth letter from the left):

[image]

Now for chrome, I was able to fix it by applying the svg format

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Noto Sans Hebrew';
        src: url('NotoSansHebrew-Regular.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }


    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Noto Sans Hebrew';
        src: url('NotoSansHebrew-Bold.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight: bold;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

But firefox won't budge. I tried giving it a specific format like I did with chrome (I tried `woff`, `eot`, `ttf`, `svg`), but nothing. It keeps looking like that.

What can I do?

**p.s.**
Don't tell me about fontsquirrel. Besides the fact that they blacklist noto-sans, I already tried using their suggested format for defining font-face (also the css file you import from google is [just like it anyway](http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanshebrew.css)).

Comment: So how did you generate the font files from the .ttf files, if not with FontSquirrel?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I tried two different services I found on the internet (it was a while ago, I'm not sure I can trace exactly which). After seeing no change, I reverted to simply importing Google's CSS file (which includes the relevant formats)